# How to block an Lua script from running

Tags: lua, coroutine, lua-api

I am designing a RPG in C. It's gotten to the point that I've implemented a scripting system. I decided to embed Lua into my game. Currently I register a set of commands in C that I call in Lua.

How do I block an Lua script from running until a command's done? For instance when a textbox appears, the script should stop running until the player presses ENTER and clears the textbox. Or when a wait function is issued.

How do I accomplish this? Preferably in C.

Comment: A script can `coroutine.yield()`, and later you can continue it by `lua_resume()`

Comment: What do I pass to lua_resume()?

Comment: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_resume

Comment: If I am to use coroutine functions, how do I identify it in C?

Comment: Read the Lua manual about coroutines, and if something stays unclear create a new question with "lua"+"coroutine" tags and post your code.

Comment: Assuming you're running your scripts once per frame you could just check the relevant conditions before actually running them.